# Tinymce issue with svelte

Tags: tinymce, svelte, sveltekit

I am using SDK and Svelte component for Tinymce but getting an error the frequency of that error in Windows is high but low in Mac.
The issue is getting an error in the console ->
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'select')
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parse')